# Geometric proof of Borel-Weil theorem

Tags: lie-groups, vector-bundles

I am curious if there is any geometric proof of Borel-Weil theorem.

Borel-Weil is a geometric realization of irreducible unitary representation. The proofs I found, however, all use Weyl unitarian trick from the start, and move on to prove the irreducibility of a representation of the complexified Lie group. The proofs are more or less about holomorphic functions on the complex Lie group instead of special sections on $G/T$. I am wondering if there is a proof of the theorem which deals directly with $G/T$?

Comment: You need some complex structures around to say what a holomorphic section of the relevant line bundles are. One way to get those complex structures is to complexify and then choose a Borel in the complexification containing $T$. If you don't want to do this, then where are you getting complex structures from?

Comment: Yes, a proof deals directly with $G/T$ exist. The only thing is to find a complex structure on it. As usual, we first construct an almost complex structure, then we show it is integrable. In fact, the decoposition $T(G/T)=G\times_T(\mathfrak{n}^+\oplus\mathfrak{n}^-)$ gives the almost complex structure, and $[\mathfrak{n}^+,\mathfrak{n}^+]\subset \mathfrak{n}^+$ show integrability. Here $\mathfrak{n}^\pm$ is the positive(negative) root space.

Comment: You might like Bott's short survey "On induced representations" in The mathematical heritage of Hermann Weyl (Durham, NC, 1987), 1–13, 
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 48, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1988. Personally, I find it a _lot_ easier to use complex algebraic geometry to think about Borel-Weil (much less Borel-Weil-Bott!) but to each his own.